# Only the first item is displayed from the ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I have made an `EditText` and a `Button`.  The click of the button should save the text from the `EditText`into the `ArrayList`.  The `ArrayList` is then persisted to a file.  Further clicks append the text from the `EditText` to the `ArrayList` and then the file.  However, after saving the file, I can only retrieve the **first item entered** from the file. I want to retrieve the whole list in a comma-separated format.

**Button Click code:**

```
    String filename =“abc.text”;
    List arrlist = new ArrayList();
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String listtext = a1.getText().toString();
            // a1 is edittext
            if (listtext.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter product", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                arrlist.add(listtext);
                a1.setText("");
                try {
                    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_APPEND);
                    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                    oos.writeObject(arrlist);
                    oos.close();
                    fos.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

**Retrieval of ArrayList from file:**

```
List newarrList = new ArrayList();

FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(filename);
ObjectInputStream restore = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
newarrList= (ArrayList)restore.readObject();
restore.close();

String joined = TextUtils.join(", ", newarrList);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),joined,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
// only the first item is displayed, not sure why
```

Comment: Do you save in a file a List with only 1 String for any reason? Why don't you save the String?

Comment: You keep adding ArrayList objects to the file using the ObjectInputStream.  But you only read a single one out.  I think you want to keep around a single ArrayList and update the file instead of appending to it.

Comment: Close the streams in **finally block**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keep adding `ArrayList` objects to the file using the `ObjectInputStream`.  But you only read a single one out.  I think you want to keep around a single `ArrayList` that you add the data to and then save that single `ArrayList` to the file whenever a click occurs instead of appending multiple `ArrayList`s for each entry.

```
List arrist = new ArrayList();
arrlist.add(listtext);
a1.setText("");
try {
  FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_APPEND);
  ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
```

appending an ArrayList object with only one entry each time an onclick occurs

```
  oos.writeObject(arrlist);
  oos.close();
  fos.close();
}...
```

If you want to keep your original code and the state is only held for a single Activity and no persistence between Activity changes/App restarts etc.. then this should work.

```
final String filename = "abc.text";
File file = new File(filename);
// moved out of onClickListener
final List arrlist = new ArrayList();
try {
        // load the previous contents if it exists

        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(filename);
        ObjectInputStream restore = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        ArrayList newArrList = (ArrayList) restore.readObject();
        arrlist.addAll(newArrList);
        restore.close();
        fis.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // ignore, maybe log
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (OptionalDataException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) 
    e.printStackTrace()
}

b2.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v
            ) {

                String listtext = a1.getText().toString();     //a1 is edittext

                if (listtext.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter product", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {

                    arrlist.add(listtext);
                    a1.setText("");
                    try {
```

Change `Context.MODE_APPEND` to `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` otherwise we keep inflating the file with junk

```
                        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                        oos.writeObject(arrlist);
                        oos.close();
                        fos.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
);
```

The other alternative is to not use the `ObjectInputStream` but just a straight FileOutputStream and append the `String` contents on each click.

Comment: the problem was that the append is still happening to the file.  So the first time you click you will write an `ArrayList` with a single entry.  The second time you click you will write another ArrayList with two entries.  But your read only reads the first `ArrayList` and that only contains the first entry.  Removing the `Context.MODE_APPEND` to 
    `FileOutputStream   fos = openFileOutput(filename);`
should fix it.

Comment: `FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(filename);` doesn't work. `openFileOutput(filename, should have something)` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput(java.lang.String, int)

Comment: Use `openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)`

Comment: `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` solves it somewhat. But now a different issue has cropped up. When the app restarts the `ArrayList` saved on file is not appended on entering new items. A new list gets created when items are entered to it everytime when the app restarts.

Comment: This is what I stated above that you will have a problem with persistence.  You can change it to load from the file when the Activity/App starts up and populate the `ArrayList` so it will have your previous entries.

Comment: Can you give an example how to **load from the file when the Activity/App starts up and populate the** `ArrayList`

Comment: I updated the code above to load the file if it exists (I didn't add Exception handling not sure if you are doing that in an outer scope of the code or not.
See above for better formatting of the following -> `if (file.exists()) {FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(filename) ;
  ObjectInputStream restore = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
  ArrayList newarrList = (ArrayList)restore.readObject();
  arrList.addAll(newarrList);
  restore.close();
  fis.close();
}`

Comment: Okay my check to see if the `File` existed was incorrect.  See the above corrections to my answer

Comment: @Ted did you try the above code and did it work for you?   I set it up locally and it worked fine.

Comment: I stongly believe `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` creates a new file and overwrites the previous and that seems to be the issue.

Comment: It does but if you are reading it first then writing the data when it is added then it should work. Have you tried the latest code that I update recently?

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Missed out a silly thing. **Corrected** `String joined = TextUtils.join(", ", newarrList);` **to**  `joined = TextUtils.join(", ", newArrList );`

Comment: Cool, glad you found it.

Answer (score 0):

You store(**write**) string into file, end the string with comma, and After reading__(**read**) split the result with "," which returns a String array. Make sure you are appending the string into file. `ArrayList` variable as global variable.

```
    //global variable
    List arrlist = new ArrayList();
    ......
    //write to file
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               String listtext = a1.getText().toString(); 
    .....
    arrlist.add(listtext);
    .....
    listtext = listtext + ",";
    FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("file name here", Context.MODE_APPEND);
    fOut.write(listtext .getBytes());
    fOut.close();
    ....
    }

    //reading from file
    String fileContent = readFile();
    String[] items = TextUtils.split(fileContent, ",");
```

Comment: this will fail because of the `Context.MODE_APPEND`.  His read only reads the first entry.  See my answer below

Comment: Sorry I moved out of the Question. Actually I am storing string not object. @Beggs thanks.

Comment: I made the same mistake at first.